# Can't press Ctrl and Shift while moving in games with WASD

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

When I'm playing video games like Portal 2 or Left 4 Dead on my Asus Transformer T100, I can not press/hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (to walk slowly, instead of running) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (to crouch).

Holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and then moving is possible, but it doesn't work when I'm running using WASD keys and I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or hold down both keys at the same time.

I face this problem with every game I play on my T100. Remapping keys, I changed crouch from <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to <kbd>Q</kbd>, which works but I'd rather keep crouching on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and walk with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

Comment: It could be the case of [keyboard ghosting](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx)... though I'm not sure

Comment: hey thanks for Your reply, yes i checked there. when i hold W, S, A, or D it lights green but when i add shift or ctrl they wont light green! When i hold CTRL or SHIFT (they light green) and i add W, S, A, or D they also light green... Hmmm, how can i fix tthis issue ? Thanks !

Comment: some more info on how to test: http://uberoptions.net/logitech-keyblocking

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it appears that your problem is indeed from keyboard ghosting. The problem you are having is a hardware problem of your keyboard and there is nothing you can "do" to change the keyboard's behavior.

Your only options are to either remap the keys like you did or buy a new keyboard that has a more powerful encoder that will not ghost the keys you want to all press at the same time.